# fread(); problema na implementação

Tags: c, c++, funções

Estou com um problema simples. Consigo utilizar a função `fread` normalmente para trabalhar com processamento de áudio em C. No caso tenho 2 códigos. O primeiro lê um arquivo .WAV (com `fread`) e salva em um arquivo .CSV. Esta etapa está funcionando corretamente, pois já verifiquei o .csv com o matlab. Porém, no segundo código quando tento abrir o arquivo .CSV só retorna lixo da memória. Então criei um arquivo .txt com apenas 1 numero e tentei acessá-lo através da função `fread` e mesmo assim retorna lixo.

Segue o código:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){

    FILE *fp;
    //Este arquivo contem apenas o digito 1.
    fp = fopen("ex.txt","r");
    int text[100];

    fread(text, sizeof(text),1,fp);

    printf("%d",text[0]);

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Qual seria o problema principal? Conheço os outros métodos como `fgets` e `fscanf` porém gostaria de utilizar o `fread`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seu programa possui vários pequenos problemas e você parece ter a ideia correta, mas com problemas na implementação para uma linguagem de nível mais baixo como C.

Inicialmente, vamos deixar claro que a função `fread` lê bytes consecutivos do stream que você especificou e, daí, coloca esses bytes lidos de forma "binária" na memória que você especificar.

Note-se que, aqui, `fread` **não** faz interpretação/conversão da representação textual de números (por exemplo, a sequência de caracteres `1`) para a forma "interna" do computador (a representação binária dele, que pode ser [*big* ou *little-endian*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extremidade_(ordena%C3%A7%C3%A3o))).

Se o seu arquivo `ex.txt` tiver única e exclusivamente o dígito 1 na forma de texto, o que estará no arquivo será (muito provavelmente, codificado em [latin1](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) ou [UTF-8](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)) um único byte e a função `fread` lerá esse byte (para o caractere `1` a representação interna, com essas codificações que eu falei, será 49 (o valor "[ASCII](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)" do 1)) e colocará o conteúdo desse byte na memória de endereço `&text` (não é erro o `&`).

Em computadores "populares" (ARMs, PowerPCs, i386, amd64 etc.), um inteiro possui tamanho de 4 bytes e, portanto, quando você lê a posição de memória `text[0]` para imprimir com `printf`, você estará lendo o número 1 e mais 3 outros bytes que podem ser algum lixo.

(Além disso, a maioria dos computadores que temos à nossa disposição é little-endian).

No meu computador (rodando Debian GNU/Linux testing, com GCC 8.2.1 e biblioteca C glibc 2.28), se eu colocar um arquivo `ex.txt` com o dígito 1 seguido de new-line (isto é, `'\n'`, que possui código ASCII 10) e eu executar o seu programa, eu obtenho o número 2609, que faz completo sentido, já que 2609 = 49 + 10 * 256 e isso é consistente com o computador ser little-endian:

- primeiro, o byte de número 49 está na memória
- depois, o byte de número 10 está na memória

(Provavelmente, zeros foram colocados no restante da memória reservada para `text` no meu sistema, mas não se deve contar com isso).

Seu código ainda possui alguns outros problemas (além de indentação/espaçamento), mas um dos principais é que você declara o vetor `text` como vetor de `int`s, mas parece querer colocar dados arbitrários (binários), se você insiste em usar `fgets` (`fscanf` ou `fgets` fariam a interpretação das sequências de caracteres para a representação interna do computador).

Supondo-se que você queira ainda usar a sequência binária nas suas manipulações, você deveria, depois de fazer a leitura dos dados como você já fez:

- fazer a leitura da região de memória `text` com um ponteiro para `char`s
- usar a string de formatação `%c` no `printf`
- declarar o vetor `text` como apenas de `char`s (não é estritamente necessário, mas evita uma grande quantidade de "sambadas" com ponteiros)

Honestamente, é mais simples usar `fgets` (geralmente, mais seguro do que outras opções) e deixar `fread` apenas para quando você quiser os dados binários do arquivo.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela explicação! É exatamente o que eu estava precisando entender.

Comment: @GabrielLavoura, é um prazer. Eu editei a minha resposta para colocar alguns links para a Wikipédia que dão mais informações/contexto para quem vier a ler a reposta.